# Python: For loop pattern

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
print("Enter the width")
a=int(input())
count=0
for i in range(1,a+1):
    print("*"*i)
    if i==a:
       count=1
    if count==1:
       i-=2
```

I want a pattern like this

```
*
**
***
****
*****
****
***
**
*
```

when user inputs 5 as the width. But the output I am getting is just

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You can remove the first `print` and just use `a=int(input("Enter the width"))`

Comment: At the top of the loop, `i` gets the next value from the `range`. Altering `i` at the end of your loop doesn't affect the next loop.

Answer (score 3):

So if you want 10 entries with *'s then you need bigger range, that's why I put `2*a+1`. Then you need to change `count` value, not `i`.

```
print("Enter the width")
a=int(input())
count=1
for i in range(1,2*a+1):
    print(count*"*")
    if i<a:
       count+=1
    elif i>=a:
       count-=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of putting this could be:

```py
print('Enter the max width:')
max_count = int(input())

for count in range(1, 2 * max_count):
    prepared_count = count if count <= max_count else 2 * max_count - count
    print ''.ljust(prepared_count, '*')
```